# Tidytext - set expressions as a single token

Tags: r, tidytext

I am trying to separate my text data into tokens using the unnest_tokens function from the tidytext package. The thing is that some expressions appear multiple times and I would like to keep them a single token instead of multiple tokens.

Normal outcome:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Id = c(1, 2),
  Text = c('A first nice text', 'A second nice text')
)

df %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text)

  Id   Word
1  1      a
2  1  first
3  1   nice
4  1   text
5  2      a
6  2 second
7  2   nice
8  2   text
```

What I would like (expression = "nice text"):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Id = c(1, 2),
  Text = c('A first nice text', 'A second nice text')
)

df %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text)

  Id   Word
1  1      a
2  1  first
3  1   nice text
4  2      a
5  2 second
6  2   nice text
```

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concise solution based on negative lookahead `(?!...)`, to disallow `separate_rows` to separate `Text` on whitespace `\\s` if there's `nice` to the left of `\\s` and `text` to its right (`\\b`are word boundary anchors, in case you have, say, "nice text**s**", which you *do* want to separate)

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate_rows(Text, sep = "(?!\\bnice\\b)\\s(?!\\btext\\b)")
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     Id Text     
  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 A        
2     1 first    
3     1 nice text
4     2 A        
5     2 second   
6     2 nice text
```

A more advanced regex is with `(*SKIP)(*F)`:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(Text, sep = "(\\bnice text\\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s")
```

For more info: [How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

Comment: That is waht I had in mind. A solution with regex taht excludes „nice text“ from the split.

Answer (score 1):

A bit verbose, and there might be an option to exclude certain phrases in the unnest_tokens, but it does the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
df <- data.frame(Id = c(1, 2),,
                 Text = c('A first nice text', 'A second nice text')) %>%
  unnest_tokens('Word', Text)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarize(Word = paste(if_else(lag(Word) == 'nice' & Word == 'text', 'nice text', Word))) %>%
  mutate(temp_id = row_number()) %>%
  filter(temp_id != temp_id[Word == 'nice text'] - 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-temp_id)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     Id Word     
  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 a        
2     1 first    
3     1 nice text
4     2 a        
5     2 second   
6     2 nice text
```